# Why do we apply Laplace transform into an exponential curve?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, graphing-functions, laplace-transform

I am doing my school report on newton’s law of cooling and I was wondering how could I analyze the graph of the exponential curve for newton’s law of cooling and found the interesting concept of Laplace transform and so I was wondering how could this concept be applied to the exponential curve I got and what would be the reason behind applying this concept?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a run-on sentence btw.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t quite understand what you meant

Comment: Oh, I meant that your question consists of like three separate sentences that have been crammed into one long sentence. You should break it up into a few sentences rather than one long sentence. I know this doesn't address the content of your question, but it's maybe more important than the question. Can't go through life writing like that.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for letting me know.

Comment: One possible place you could look: chapter 6 of the textbook [Boyce, DiPrima, and Meade](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems-ebook/dp/B073WNJ13R) gives a pretty decent explanation of how you can use the Laplace transform to solve various types of ODEs, including the ODE that appears in Newton's model of cooling. I'm sure you can find the same material explained elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: But also, it's possible to solve the PDE that appears in Newton's model of cooling without using the Laplace transform at all. That would be the simplest thing to do.